# Reducing the amount of return statements

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic

The following code returns the BMI risk of a person - either *Low*, *Medium* or *High*.
It works perfectly fine. However, I was wondering if there is another way to solve it without using too many return statements.

Is there any other way, either, Pythonic or logically to make it any shorter?

```
def bmi_risk(bmi, age):
    ''' function returning bmi's risk on human '''
    if bmi < 22 and age < 45:
        return "Low"
    if bmi < 22 and age >= 45:
        return "Medium"
    if bmi >= 22 and age < 45:
        return "Medium"
    if bmi >= 22 and age >= 45:
        return "High"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the best, or at least clearest, way is through the use of [multiple `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) with a variable holding the risk:

```
def bmi_risk(bmi, age):
    ''' function returning bmi's risk on human '''
    if bmi < 22 and age < 45:
        risk = "Low"
    elif bmi < 22 and age >= 45:
        risk = "Medium"
    elif bmi >= 22 and age < 45:
        risk = "Medium"
    elif bmi >= 22 and age >= 45:
        risk = "High"
    else:
        risk = "Unknown"
    return risk
```

At the least, this allows you to do extra checks on `risk` after assigning it but before returning.

---

There is a very subjective discussion to be had about single or multiple returns in programming languages - especially ones like Python that have automatic garbage collection.

There isn't anything terrible *wrong* with your code, and multiple returns allow for early return when needed. For example:

```
def my_function(argument1, argument2):
    if some_obvious_error_condition:
        return "ERR"

    # 100 lines of complex code

    return other_thing
```

Answer (score 3):

There are only 3 options. If it's not low or high then it must be medium. So after checking for low and high you can just return medium:

```
def bmi_risk(bmi, age):
    ''' function returning bmi's risk on human '''
    if bmi < 22 and age < 45:
        return "Low"
    if bmi >= 22 and age >= 45:
        return "High"
    return "Medium"
```

A less readable but more compact form is to use a table and compute an index into it based on the conditions, which represents the sum of risk factors:

```
def bmi_risk(bmi, age, risktable=["Low", "Medium", "High"]):
    return risktable[(1 if (bmi >= 22) else 0) + (1 if (age >= 45) else 0)]
```

Alternatively (thanks @ZeroPiraeus):

```
def bmi_risk(bmi, age, risktable=["Low", "Medium", "High"]):
    return risktable[(bmi >= 22) + (age >= 45)]
```

Comment: A more compact (and arguably more readable) version of your second function could be `return risktable[(bmi >= 22) + (age >= 45)]` ...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using dictionary,

```
age = 45
bmi = 22

age1 = int(input("Age:"))
bmi1 = int(input("BMI:"))

test1 =  {(age1 < age and bmi1 < bmi) : "Low",
(age1 >= age and bmi1 < bmi) : "Medium",
(age1 < age and bmi1 >= bmi) : "Medium1",
(age1 >= age and bmi1 >= bmi) : "High", }

if True in test1:
    print(test1[True])
    
else:
    print("Unknown")
```

```
Age:22
BMI:44
Medium1

[Program finished]
```